# ROS 2 Humble: RCLError: Failed to publish: Publisher;s contexxt is invalid

Tags: ros2, publisher, ros-humble, wheeled-robot, irobot

I am at the start of my journey learning to use ROS 2 Humble with the iRobot Create 3.

I wrote a publisher to its light ring leds that allow me to override the control to the light ring and change the colours and then revert control back to the robot, changing the light ring back to all white when using a keyboard interrupt. The first part of the publisher works, allowing me to play with the light ring leds but I keep getting the following error when using the interrupt.

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/benjyl/irobot_ws/src/py_pubsub/py_pubsub/pub_lightring_2.py", line 136, in <module>  
    main() 
  File "/home/benjyl/irobot_ws/src/py_pubsub/py_pubsub/pub_lightring_2.py", line 129, in main  
    led_publisher.reset()   
  File "/home/benjyl/irobot_ws/src/py_pubsub/py_pubsub/pub_lightring_2.py", line 105, in reset  
    self.lights_publisher.publish(self.lightring)    
  File "/opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/publisher.py", line 70, in publish
    self.__publisher.publish(msg)
rclpy._rclpy_pybind11.RCLError: Failed to publish: publisher's context is invalid, at ./src/rcl/publisher.c:389.
```

I haven't come across anyone else who has had the same error and I don't understand what it means when a "publisher's context is invalid". Could someone please help?

Here's the code for the publisher:

```
import sys
import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node

# The lighring msg is made up of LedColor msgs so both needed
from irobot_create_msgs.msg import LightringLeds
from irobot_create_msgs.msg import LedColor

namespace = '' # currently robot has no namespace assigned

class LEDPublisher(Node):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('led_publisher')

        # Publish lightringleds message over the topic cmd_lightring
        # queue size - 10: queue size is a quality of service (qos) setting limiting queue size, like for subscriber when specificying type of data received
        self.lights_publisher = self.create_publisher(LightringLeds, namespace + '/cmd_lightring', 10)
        self.lightring = LightringLeds()
        self.lightring.override_system = True # allows overriding of the light system, required in the lightringleds message as well as the ledcolors

        timer_period = 2 # how many seconds between consecutive messages published
        self.timer = self.create_timer(timer_period, self.timer_callback)

    
    def timer_callback(self, r=0, g=0, b=255):
        """Control loop publishing the control command to the LED lightring

        Args:
            r (int, optional): LED red channel value. Defaults to 0.
            g (int, optional): LED green channel value. Defaults to 0.
            b (int, optional): LED blue channel value. Defaults to 0.
        """
        print(f"Changing light values to: r={r}, g={g}, b={b}")
        self.lightring.leds= [LedColor(red=r, green=g, blue=b), LedColor(red=r, green=g, blue=b),
                              LedColor(red=r, green=g, blue=b), LedColor(red=r, green=g, blue=b), 
                              LedColor(red=r, green=g, blue=b), LedColor(red=r, green=g, blue=b)]
        self.lights_publisher.publish(self.lightring) # publish the message
    
    def reset(self):
        """
        Return control of the lightring back to the robot and reset all leds to white
        """
        self.lightring.override_system = False
        white = [LedColor(red=255, green=255, blue=255), LedColor(red=255, green=255, blue=255), LedColor(red=255, green=255, blue=255),
                 LedColor(red=255, green=255, blue=255), LedColor(red=255, green=255, blue=255), LedColor(red=255, green=255, blue=255)]
        self.lightring.leds = white
        self.lights_publisher.publish(self.lightring)
        
    def main(args=None):
        rclpy.init(args=args)
        led_publisher = LEDPublisher()
    
        try:
            rclpy.spin(led_publisher) # spin nodes so callbacks (in this case just the timer callback) called
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("\nCaught Keyboard interrupt")
        finally:
            print("Done")
            led_publisher.reset()
            led_publisher.destroy_node()
            print("Shutting down")
            rclpy.shutdown()
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Thanks

Comment: (This is not a solution but a way to debug the problem) Can you insert a delay/sleep before calling `led_publisher.destroy_node()` and see if that makes a difference? Recommend trying out different wait times. See https://answers.ros.org/question/390575/turtlesim-spawn-service-error-rcl-nodes-context-is-invalid/.

Comment: I’ve been seeing this class of “ungraceful” node shutdowns for the last several years, even on official ROS 2 tutorial nodes.  I’ve tried commenting out the final destroy() statement with some success, but certainly feel your frustration as a noob trying to learn how to code ROS 2 and seeing error messages at lines you didn’t write!

Comment: @abishek47 - I tried that with 2 second and 5 second delays using time.sleep inserted after the line led_publisher.reset() but the error appeared as soon as I used the keyboard interrupt

Comment: @CyclicalObsessive, I'll give commenting it out a go